# Appcelerator - Saving image to a file from ImageView with fixed resolution

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to save the content of an ImageView into a file and save it as an image. The simple code snippet which I am using is:

```
writeImageToFile(imageView.image);
```

The function writeImageToFile, saves the blob in a file which contains the image displayed in the image view. All good and fine till here.

Now the point noticed in here is that, I have defined the ImageView with the width and height as 150dip. After saving the image into a file, for iPhone 5, we find that the image resolution is 300x300, and for iPhone 6 Plus it is 450x450. The image resolution varies with the screen density, which I can understand.

But my query is that is there any way to always keep the resolution fixed to 150x150 pixels. Am not sure if this is possible out of the box with Appcelerator or do we need to use external modules.

Note: This is also applicable for Android too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Blob functions to check the image size, then decide if you need to resize. You can use imageAsResized (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob-method-imageAsResized) to make a 150x150 image.